# Latex: Creating several new layers of subsections results in some counting bugs

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I tried to create a way of expanding the number of section layers in Latex. The current Layers `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` weren't enough and `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` caused problems with other libraries. So I created a sectioning system that could include seven layers going `\section`, `\subsection`, `\twosubsection`, `\threesubsection`, `\foursubsection`, ... . The code mostly originated from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172658).

But when I implement a threesubsections in multiple twosubsections, the counter does not reset (see example below). Furthermore the Sections of the appendix are numbered the wrong way. The first subsection is supposed to be numbered as A.1 instead of 1.1.

Can you think of a solution to this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{appendix}

%% Section-Titles ---------------------------------

% Deklaration of the section functions
\newcommand{\twosubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{#1}}
\titleclass{\threesubsection}{straight}[\subsubsection]
\titleclass{\foursubsection}{straight}[\threesubsection]
\titleclass{\fivesubsection}{straight}[\foursubsection]
\titleclass{\sixsubsection}{straight}[\fivesubsection]

% Counters
\newcounter{threesubsection}
\newcounter{foursubsection}
\newcounter{fivesubsection}
\newcounter{sixsubsection}

% Format of the section titles
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\threesubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thethreesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\foursubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thefoursubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\fivesubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thefivesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\sixsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thesixsubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

% Spacing of the section titles
\titlespacing*{\twosubsection}
  {0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\threesubsection}
  {0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5em}
\titlespacing*{\foursubsection}
  {0pt}{1.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\fivesubsection}
  {0pt}{1.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\sixsubsection}
  {0pt}{1.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}

% Configuration of the Counters
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\thethreesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{threesubsection}}
\renewcommand\thefoursubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{threesubsection}.\arabic{foursubsection}}
\renewcommand\thefivesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{threesubsection}.\arabic{foursubsection}.\arabic{fivesubsection}}
\renewcommand\thesixsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{threesubsection}.\arabic{foursubsection}.\arabic{fivesubsection}.\arabic{sixsubsection}}

\makeatletter

% ToC counters
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}
\def\toclevel@threesubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@foursubsection{5}
\def\toclevel@fivesubsection{6}
\def\toclevel@sixsubsection{7}

% ToC format
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.5em}{3em}}
\newcommand*\l@threesubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{6.5em}{4em}}
\newcommand*\l@foursubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10.5em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@fivesubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{15.5em}{6em}}
\newcommand*\l@sixsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{21.5em}{7em}}

\makeatother

%% == Document ===========================================
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\twosubsection{Subsubsection}

\threesubsection{Subsubsubsection}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\twosubsection{Subsubsection}

\threesubsection{Subsubsubsection with wrong counter}

\appendix

\section{Appendix Section}

\subsection{Appendix Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be done easily using `chngcntr` package and the command `\counterwithin{threesubsection}{subsubsection}`

For renumbering of subsections in the appendix, you might include the following

`\preto{\appendix}{\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}. \arabic{subsection}}}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{appendix}

%% Section-Titles ---------------------------------

% Deklaration of the section functions
\newcommand{\twosubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{#1}}
\titleclass{\threesubsection}{straight}[\subsubsection]
\titleclass{\foursubsection}{straight}[\threesubsection]
\titleclass{\fivesubsection}{straight}[\foursubsection]
\titleclass{\sixsubsection}{straight}[\fivesubsection]

% Counters
\newcounter{threesubsection}
\newcounter{foursubsection}
\newcounter{fivesubsection}
\newcounter{sixsubsection}

% Format of the section titles
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thesubsubsection}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\threesubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thethreesubsection}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\foursubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thefoursubsection}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\fivesubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thefivesubsection}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\sixsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thesixsubsection}
{1em}
{}

% Spacing of the section titles
\titlespacing*{\twosubsection}
{0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\threesubsection}
{0pt}{2.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5em}
\titlespacing*{\foursubsection}
{0pt}{1.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\fivesubsection}
{0pt}{1.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\sixsubsection}
{0pt}{1.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}

% Configuration of the Counters
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\thethreesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{threesubsection}}
\renewcommand\thefoursubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{threesubsection}.\arabic{foursubsection}}
\renewcommand\thefivesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{threesubsection}.\arabic{foursubsection}.\arabic{fivesubsection}}
\renewcommand\thesixsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{threesubsection}.\arabic{foursubsection}.\arabic{fivesubsection}.\arabic{sixsubsection}}

\makeatletter

% ToC counters
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}
\def\toclevel@threesubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@foursubsection{5}
\def\toclevel@fivesubsection{6}
\def\toclevel@sixsubsection{7}

% ToC format
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.5em}{3em}}
\newcommand*\l@threesubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{6.5em}{4em}}
\newcommand*\l@foursubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10.5em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@fivesubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{15.5em}{6em}}
\newcommand*\l@sixsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{21.5em}{7em}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{threesubsection}{subsubsection}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\appendix}{\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}. \arabic{subsection}}}

%% == Document ===========================================
\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{Section}
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    \twosubsection{Subsubsection}
    
    \threesubsection{Subsubsubsection}
    
    \section{Section}
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    
    \twosubsection{Subsubsection}
    
    \threesubsection{Subsubsubsection with correct counter}
    
    \appendix
    
    \section{Appendix Section}
    
    \subsection{Appendix Subsection}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked for the section numbering. Thabks a lot!
Doyou  have a solution for the appendix section numbering?